# Problem with \foreach and \input

Tags: input, foreach

I am having a problem using \foreach to import a variable amount of files into my latex template. This is the code I am using for this particular part:

```
\documentclass[8pt,handout,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \filenumber in {01,02,...,99}{
  \edef\ExerciseFile{collection_04_ex\filenumber}
  \edef\SolutionFile{collection_04_sol\filenumber}
  \IfFileExists{\ExerciseFile}{\input{\ExerciseFile}}

  \IfFileExists{\SolutionFile}{\input{\SolutionFile}}
}

\end{document}
```

There are two files per file number, the first includes an exercise, and the second the solution. So I want to include them *in that order*. But running this generates errors like "Missing $ Inserting}", "Missing } Inserting}", or "Undefined Control Sequence". If I do this loop for one of the file types, it works. Doing exercise first and solution separately also works. What drives me almost insane is that the code above *sometimes* works.

(In Detail: Comment out the line `\IfFileExists{\SolutionFile}{\input{\SolutionFile}}` and change `\IfFileExists{\ExerciseFile}{\input{\ExerciseFile}}` to `\IfFileExists{\ExerciseFile}{\input{\ExerciseFile}{\SolutionFile}}`. This generates an error, but changing it back to the above example works for some reason).

There must be an error in my code, but I can't figure it out..

Edit: typo

Comment: Sounds like it depends on what's in the file. When you `\input` a file TeX processes the whole thing right then, so if there's any problem in the files you could get those errors. Do the solution files use any commands that are defined or redefined in the exercise files?

Comment: I checked the files, just to be sure. The solution files are self contained, no new definitions or renews. The structure for the solution files is quite simple, too: They start with `\subsection{Solution:}` followed by `{ }` containing the body. If I edit the `\foreach` loop such that only solution files are read, it works without problems... (same if only exercise files are read).

Comment: `_` does subscript in math mode, so if `\ExerciseFile`, say, is used in text, to typeset something, the `missing $` error generates. `\input` detokenizes its parameter, so a standalone `\SolutionFile` would do the`$` error too. Unrelated: the looping does `01,02,3,4,5,`...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in the loop, I wasn't aware of that.
I think I understand what you meant. The underscores in the filenames cause issues with reading the file contents. Indeed, removing the underscores from the filenames fixes the issue. Now, my only problem is that the loop generates an extra page with the filename of the solution only.